# Pandas .txt-file into .csv-file -- Delimiter/Seperator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

i am having a problem turning a given .txt-file into a .csv-file.
I need to turn:

```
Ch   Len  Typ   Delta t                 Time                   Data

00   08   16    00:18:41.728.560.640    00:18:41.728.560.640   9D A1 31 29

00   08   00    00:00:00.000.993.280    00:18:41.729.553.920   1D A0 32 2B
```

into:

```
Ch,Len,Typ,Delta t,Time,Data

00,08,16,00:18:41.728.560.640,00:18:41.728.560.640,9D A1 31 29

00,08,00,00:00:00.000.993.280,00:18:41.729.553.920,1D A0 32 2B
```

I have tried reading the .txt-file with pandas but I don't know how to seperate the different tabbings. For example the spaces between the data bytes need to be ignored.

```
df = pd.read_csv(self.complete_filename, sep='\s+')
df.to_csv('this_csv.csv')
```

Maybe you can help me out.
Thank you!

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far. For the second step please use correct upper case letters.

Comment: Are the separators tabs or multiple spaces? Try `sep='\t'` or `sep='\s{2,}'`

Comment: 'sep='\s{2,}' worked for me - thank you! But at the beginning of each row is a counter. How can I disable it?

Comment: @nikBRK Just have a look at the [pandas reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: Yes - stupid question from me - got it!